# Apache: Redirection with RewriteMap is not working

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect

I recently migrated my personal blog to another publication system. So I want to redirect the URL with the old scheme to the new ones.

I have a redirect map which looks like this (my domain is `ailothaen.fr` ) :

```
/a/?d=2017/02/22/11/00/53-les-conteneurs-une-nouvelle-fonctionnalite-tres-interessante-de-firefox https://ailothaen.fr/a/?post/2017/02/Les-conteneurs%2C-une-nouvelle-fonctionnalit%C3%A9-tr%C3%A8s-int%C3%A9ressante-de-Firefox
/a/?d=2017/06/24/15/00/00-les-raccourcis-dans-firefox https://ailothaen.fr/a/?post/2017/06/Les-raccourcis-dans-Firefox
/a/?d=2017/07/08/11/55/06-changer-les-icones-de-7zip https://ailothaen.fr/a/?post/2017/07/Changer-les-icones-de-7zip
```

And I put this in my virtualhost configuration:

```
# 301 redirect old blog URLs
RewriteMap oldBlogSystem "txt:/etc/apache2/maps/oldBlogSystem.txt"
RewriteCond ${oldBlogSystem:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${oldBlogSystem:$1} [R=301,L]
```

However, when I'm trying to go to, for example, `ailothaen.fr/a/?d=2017/07/08/11/55/06-changer-les-icones-de-7zip`, the URL is not being redirected, like it was not catched by the redirection system.

I tried to remove or add the domain in my map file, but redirections still do not work. Is there something I am missing out?

Comment: RewriteLog should be turned on in this case to investigate your problem, (and turned of when the problem is fixed)